# Loosing Column when running dask to_parquet method with partition_on option

Tags: dask

I have data that I need to optimize in order to perform  `group_by` .
Currently I have the data in several `parquet` files (over 2.5B rows)  which looks as follows:
ID1 | ID2   | Location |
AERPLORDRVA | AOAAATDRLVA | None
ASDFGHJHASA | QWEFRFASEEW | home

I'm adding a third column in order to resave the file with partitions (and also `append` them) that will hopefully assist with the `groupby`
`df['ID4']=df.ID1.apply(lambda x: x[:2])`

When I view the `df` I see  the column like this
ID1 | ID2 | Location | ID4
AERPLORDRVA | AOAAATDRLVA | None | AE
ASDFGHJHASA | QWEFRFASEEW | home | AS
....

But when I run the following code the `ID4` column changes
`dd.to_parquet(path2newfile, df, compression='SNAPPY', partition_on = ['ID4'], has_nulls= ['Location'], fixed_text ={'ID1':11,'ID2':11,'ID4':2}`

into
`df2 = dd.read_parquet(path2newfile)`
ID1 | ID2 | Location | dir0
AERPLORDRVA | AOAAATDRLVA | None | ID4=AE
ASDFGHJHASA | QWEFRFASEEW | home | ID4=AS
....

Any ideas?

I was planning to include the `ID4` within the `groupby` an thus improve the efficacy of the query
`dfc = df.groupby(['ID4','ID1','ID2').count()`

I'm working on a single workstation with 24 cores and 190GB (although the `dask` cluster only recognizes 123.65GB)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in how directory names were parsed: apparently you are the first to use a field name containing numbers since the addition of the option for "drill"-style directory partitioning.

The fix is here: https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/pull/190 and was merged into master on 30-Jul-2017, and will eventually be released.

For the time being, you could rename your column not to include numbers.

Comment: As a side note, your ID4 column will come back as category type, because of hte grouping required to partition the data.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `category type` [and could not find information regarding this issue] - can you please reference any relevant link?

Comment: I found some information from [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-multiples-files-and-partitioned-datasets) and from the [fastparquet docs](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#categoricals) but I'm still not able to understand the various file configuration.

Comment: What file configuration is confusing you? The comment about categoricals: because, by definition, there are a small number of possible values for column ID4, after loading, the pandas dtype of the corresponding column will be "category".